# Tips for how to make tangled lines?

Tags: shapes, line-art

I'm looking to make something along this type of [line design](http://cdn.4imprint.com/prod/700/374449.jpg), but every time I try, it ends up looking very bad: messy instead of designery, uneven coverage, etc etc. I typically go for very geometric shapes (the two big design projects I'm currently working on are literally based on squares and hexagons), and I'm at a loss how to make tangled lines look good. I know about Bezier curves, obviously, and line smoothing, but that doesn't seem to be helping as much as I would like.

Are there any scripts out there that might help me? Or would you have any other suggestions on how to tackle this?

(FYI, I use CorelDRAW, sometimes with a graphics tablet, but if I absolutely need to, I can install Photoshop and give that a try)

Comment: Hey Alicja, I would suggest grabbing a pencil and sketch book and messing around for a while. The trick to this line art is the space that you leave between the lines, that's how you avoid the messy stuff. Also the level of tidy to messy can be a little subjective. I think you'll get there if you practice it outside of software, we tend to be perfectionists when we can hit undo so it sometimes slows the development of things like this ;) hope I've helped.

Comment: @Jenna Hmm, yes... You have a point. Will try your way along with Tom's. Hopefully one (or both!) will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Jenna's advice is good...never underestimate the power of pencil and paper!

Though if you can't find a pencil and paper nearby, here's one way to do it, using Photoshop.  Hopefully you will find that it informs your process somewhat in CorelDraw (which I haven't touched in years, sorry!)

1. Use the Line Tool to create lines varying distances apart.

[image]

2. Right click the layer and RASTERIZE that puppy.

[image]

3. SELECT ALL (CMD/CTRL-A) and use IMAGE > CROP so that lines don't extend off the image.

[image]

4. Go to FILTER > DISTORT > WAVE to open the wave properties dialog.

[image]

5. Choose SINE and WRAP AROUND settings.  Hit the RANDOMIZE button until you have something close to what you want, and then play with the sliders to fine tune.

[image]

6. Click OK and you've got your finished design.

[image]

There are certainly other approaches that can be used, but with this method, the proportions between lines remains consistent.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Ooh, Tom - this is an interesting idea. I'll give it a try (or, actually, a spin-off) and see what happens. Thanks!